# getting images with while loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm working on a school project where we need to make a website that can show images from a database. I'm trying to do this with the following piece of php code:

```
    <?php
        $table_name = "image";//var with database table name
        $get = "SELECT * FROM $table_name";
        $everything = mysql_query($get);

        while($pic = mysql_fetch_array($everything)){
            echo "<img scr='../img/".$pic['imgname']."' height='300px'>";
            echo " - ";
            echo "<a href='single_post.php?id".$pic['id']."'>";//link with img id to single_post 
            echo $pic['name'];//shows name from img for link
            echo"</a>";//close link
            echo"<p>";
            echo"<p><a href='admin.php'>toevoegen</a></p>";//link for new upload
        }
    ?>
```

When i run this, it doesn't show any images. I think the fault is somewhere in the first echo but i'm sure the link to the image is right so i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

some extra info:

- database connection is working. (the name's from the images does show on the webpage)
- the image scr  is correct atleast til the $pic var. (i've testet this with :`<img src="../img/tumblr_mf6x6xI6pF1qzjw8go1_400.jpg" alt="img" height="300" width="300">` )

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you connected to database? did you try `mysql_error()`?

Comment: Show the result of `print_r($pic)`. Verify `imgname` is the field name.

Comment: verify that you are getting all results of $pic = mysql_fetch_array($everything) correctly

Comment: this is the result of print_r : Array ( [0] => 11 [id] => 11 [1] => image1 [name] => image1 [2] => 1111 [bouwjaar] => 1111 [3] => 1111 [architect] => 1111 [4] => tumblr_mf6x6xI6pF1qzjw8go1_400.jpg [imgname] => tumblr_mf6x6xI6pF1qzjw8go1_400.jpg [5] => 11111 [adres] => 11111 ) 1

Comment: That looks OK. I'm guessing the path to the image is wrong. Are you sure it should be `../img/`? I think it's wrong.

Comment: yes, because i've tried to put the name of an image form that img folder in there. and it worked. so i guess the var $pics isn't working properly. but i don't know how..

Comment: It's working now. The reason why it wasn't working was the src tag in the <img/> tag. I had scr instead of src... 

Thanks for all the help!!

Answer (score 0):

i think error is because  you didn't close your img tag ..!!

try it

```
 echo "<img scr='../img/".$pic['imgname']."' height='300px'/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code
<?php
        $table_name = "image";
        $get = "SELECT * FROM $table_name";
        $everything = mysql_query($get);

        while($pic = mysql_fetch_array($everything)){?>

            <img scr="../img/<?php echo $pic['imgname']; ?>" height='300px'>

            - 

            <a href="single_post.php?id=<?php echo $pic['id'] ?>" ><?php echo $pic['name']; ?></a>

            <p><a href='admin.php'>toevoegen</a></p>     <?php   }
    ?>
```

Comment: sory for late replay..now whats status? :(

Answer (score 0):

Replace `../img/` in your code with something like `http://localhost/uploads/img/` and try.

Answer (score 0):

Check our image Color Mode in photoshop, may be it is in "CMYK". It should be in "RGB" mode.
TO convert color mode follow this link : http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-convert-from-rgb-to-cmyk-color-mode-in-phot.html